# Efficiently reschedule ActiveJob (resque/sidekiq)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque, sidekiq, rails-activejob

I'm playing with `Rails 4.2` app which uses `ActiveJob` backed by `resque/sidekiq` for email scheduling. When a user creates newsletter campaign a new job is created and scheduled on certain date. That's all great but what happens when the user changes the delivery date.

In this case every job could check if it should be delivered or not thus invalid jobs would be ignored and only the last one would be executed. This could work but if a user would make 1k edits that would push 1k-1 invalid jobs into queue - not good. I believe that the existing job should be updated or replaced with a new one. As far as I know searching through the `Redis` queue for the `job_id` is slow.

What would be the proper way for rescheduling ActiveJobs in Rails (with resque/sidekiq)?

Comment: Have you considered moving to Que, that works on top of PostgreSQL and integrates with AJ? It's fast at mass-search-update at least, I'm not sure if rescheduling is possible in it.

Comment: Thanks @D-side. I'll check if that fit into my platform.

Comment: @D-side It's funny I've never used que gem. Que's primary goal is reliability and it looks it's fast too - perfect for enterprise services.

Comment: I've actually used it in order to to have less dependencies. I've not been expecting a lot of jobs, so handing off job storage to a database I was already using seemed great. A pity that project was never completed :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is none, jobs are not meant to be rescheduled.  You have answered your own question:

> In this case every job could check if it should be delivered or not thus invalid jobs would be ignored and only the last one would be executed.

The alternative is to re-architect how you send campaigns: store the delivery date in the database and have cron check every minute for campaigns which need delivery **now** and create the Sidekiq job right then.